# how to get the nested JSON objects from SQL table in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I need to provide the below mentioned JSON output through asp.Net Web API.
this output will be used to display the organization hierarchy(treeview) in angular.

I have employees data in SQL table as below:

```
EMP_NO  EMP_NAME  DESIGNATION  Manager_ID
```

**Required JSON output:**

```
 myobject= {
      "parent":[
        {
          "name":"radha Acharya",
          "designation":"General Counsel",
          "state":"",
          "active":false
        },
        {
          "name":"Rakesh mishra",
          "designation":"General Counse2",
          "state":"",
          "active":false
        },
        {
          "name":"Suri patil",
          "designation":"General Counse3",
          "state":"",
          "active":true
        }
      ],
      "childs":[
        {
          "name":"child 1",
          "designation":"Deputy General Counsel",
          "state":"",
          "active":false,
          "hasChilds":true
        },
        {
          "name":"child 2",
          "designation":"Deputy General Counsel",
          "state":"",
          "active":false,
          "hasChilds":true
        },
        {
          "name":"child 3",
          "designation":"Deputy General Counsel",
          "state":"",
          "active":false,
          "hasChilds":false
        },
        {
          "name":"child 4",
          "designation":"Deputy General Counsel",
          "state":"",
          "active":false,
          "hasChilds":true
        },
        {
          "name":"child 5",
          "designation":"Deputy General Counsel",
          "state":"Resigned",
          "active":false,
          "hasChilds":true
        },
        {
          "name":"child 6",
          "designation":"Deputy General Counsel",
          "state":"",
          "active":false,
          "hasChilds":true
        }
      ]
    }
```

in angular it will be displaying like this
[Front end display image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfoxL.png)

Comment: How are you going to determine who is whose child from that JSON output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you plan to use the Json as there is no connection between the parent list and child list. But here is how you can have the JSON from SQL Server:

#Create Classes of type `parent` and `child`

#Create an object called `myobject` with the two array/list properties - `parent` and `childs`

#Query SQL DB and populate the `myobject` object

#Transform the `myobject` object into JSON and send from API action

```
public class parent
{
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string designation { get; set; } 
    public string state { get; set; } 
    public bool active { get; set; }
}

public class child
{
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string designation { get; set; } 
    public string state { get; set; } 
    public bool active { get; set; } 
    public bool hasChilds { get; set; }
}

public class myboject
{
    public List<Parent> parent { get; set; } 
    public List<Child> childs { get; set; }
}

myboject myboj = new myboject();
myboj.parent = new List<Parent>();
myboj.child = new List<Child>();
```

//Query your sql server database and populate the `myboj.parent` and `myboj.child` with proper data

Then do the Json transformation:

```
return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myboj);
```

That will transform the `myObj` into a json object and return.

Comment: Thanks Rahatur, now I have got an idea about this implementation, I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Virendra Glad that it helped. hope you dont mind accepting the answer and also upvoting!